# Regex friendly URL

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to create a dynamic regex to select URL's based on a segment or the whole URL.

For example, I need to get `var.match(/http:\/\/www.something.com\/something/)`

The text inside the `match()` needs to be converted so that special characters have `\` in front of them such for example `"\/"`. I was not able to find a function that converts the URL to do this? Is there one?

If not, what characters require a `\` in front?

Comment: So you're looking for a JavaScript regular-expression escape function, and/or for what characters are meaningful inside a JS regex?

Comment: The list is `[.?*+^$[\]\\(){}|-]`

From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593637/how-to-escape-regular-expression-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this to escape a string when generating a dynamic regex:

```
var specials = /[*.+?|^$()\[\]{}\\]/g;
var url_re = RegExp(url.replace(specials, "\\$&"));
```

Comment: @djechlin. It's not a reason to downvote (if it was you.)

Answer (score 0):

`( ) [ ] ? * ^ $ \ . + |` and in your case, `/` since you're using that as the delimiter in the match.

Further info mostly to pre-empt comments and downvotes:  I don't really know where `-` come from as a special character.  It's only special when inside character class brackets `[` and `]` which you're already escaping.  If you want to include characters that are *sometimes* special (which the OP doesn't) that would include look-ahead/behind characters as well, which include `=`, `<` and `>`.

Comment: @minitech in JS?  I know in grep they must actually be given a preceding `\\` to do anything, I think it's egrep in which they do not.

Comment: `j{1,5}` matches 1-5 instances of `j`. No, it does not need a preceding ``\``, at least in JavaScript, nor in any other language I've ever used... are you thinking of a different usage for `{}`?

Comment: Same usage.  Regular old `grep` does this silly thing where they count as normal and putting a backslash in front gives them special meaning.  Perl might do this?  I can't remember.  I came up with the list I posted from remembering that 1) in Perl there are 12 dirty characters and 2) they're all very basic regex constructs.